# query database for results within a certain time using the user's timezone

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

How can I query a set of results that belong to a specific time period according to the user's time.

For example: `"select * from table where datestamp like ".date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 day"))."%"`

would give me results within the past 24 hours based on the server time. How can I do this query to be based on the user's time rather than the server's time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in 3 steps:

### 1. Detect the client timezone

This is difficult:  Different browsers use different acronyms and conventions for representing names of timezones. You should use an existing implementation, like [jsTimezoneDetect](http://site.pageloom.com/automatic-timezone-detection-with-javascript).

### 2. Pass the timezone information to PHP

If you need to use timezone dependent PHP functions (like `date()` in your exemple), you can set the timezone with:

```
date_default_timezone_set($TZ);
```

Where $TZ is the variable where you stored the timezone from the client request.

### 3. Pass the timezone information to MySQL

If you need to use timezone dependent MySQL functions, you can set the timezone for the current MySQL session with:

```
mysql_query("SET time_zone = $TZ");
```

Comment: This sets the timezone within PHP or MySQL? How can I set it for both? And how would I get the user's timezone

Comment: The DATE() function I am using is a PHP function not a mysql function

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out how to get your web client timezone, please read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/how-can-i-determine-a-web-users-time-zone)

Answer (score 0):

Ask your user which timezone he's in, then subtract/add the offset to your server's time.

"The last 24 hours" are the same all over the world though, so I'd rather change the query to encompass *the last 24 hours*, not *the same day*:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `datestamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Comment: The NOW() will use the server time though I would assume?

Comment: @John Yes, but if you're looking for *"the last 24 hours"* is doesn't matter.